# PDEs of higher order than three?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Motivation for question:** I know just a little about the general theory of PDEs. I'm working on a project which happens to need examples of PDEs like Laplace's equation. The next step is to look at higher order PDEs in my investigation. I own a few PDE texts and I had hoped to find further examples, but I've noticed that the bulk of my PDE books concern mainly second order PDEs over various dimensional spaces (for example, $n=2$: $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, or $n=3$: $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u_{tt}$).

**My question is this:** do higher order equations (like $u_{xxx}=u_{tt}$, to give a silly example) have a well-developed theory?

In the case of ODEs I'm aware that we can reduce to a system of first order equations thus solutions to the $n^{th}$-order problem are furnished by the first-order theory.

Is there a similar story for PDEs? Or, is it just that higher-order PDEs are less interesting?

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: One is the [Biharmonic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation)

Comment: _Less_ interesting? This seems like an odd assumption to make.

Comment: In physics, there are solid reasons why PDEs of order $\gt 2$ are not of interest. In classical mechanics, you only need two pieces of initial data, the position and velocity, to predict the motion. In quantum mechanics, higher-derivative theories have physically unacceptable behavior: http://physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=422310

http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~gz218/2010/01/higher-derivative-theories.html

Comment: Well, less interesting in the sense that people (on the average) are not interested in it. Admittedly this is not a wise metric with which to judge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example that comes to mind is the [clamped plate equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_theory), which is of 4th order. To see how engineers approach it, [click here](http://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/plates/theory.cfm). More generally, any time your model calls for prescribed values **and** prescribed derivative on the boundary, you'll probably be dealing with a PDE of order above $2$. For second-order equations such boundary value problems are overdetermined.

There is also a general method for the Dirichlet problem for elliptic operators of any order, namely one can use [Gårding's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A5rding%27s_inequality) to verify the coercitivity assumption in the [Lax-Milgram theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem).

On the other hand, a [recent paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605302.2011.600802) by one of my colleagues  opens with a sobering statement

> There is nothing in the theory of linear strongly elliptic differential operators [of higher orders] that can be called a general existence theorem for solutions to the Neumann problem.

On the positive side, the Fourier transform goes a long way for linear PDE of all orders, especially as far as the regularity of solutions is concerned. The very size of Hörmander's 4-volume treatise "The analysis of linear partial differential operators" suggests that there is something well-developed in there.

One of the things that make second order equations easier to deal with is the fact that the calculus test for maxima/minima is the **second derivative** test. The maximum principle is a workhorse in the  theory of elliptic equations of 2nd order. In contrast, the [Hadamard maximum principle](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi712.pdf) for biharmonic equation does not go very far (see page 2 of the paper).

Comment: Sadly my journal access is pretty much just ArXiV in the short term... so I can't see your colleagues' paper. That said, the links are intriguing. I think I can use some of these equations for my project, much appreciated.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook It's pretty technical, while you are looking for the wider picture. I just used it for the quote which I happened to remember.

Answer (score 4):

For some remarks on what the general story looks like you might want to consult the Princeton Companion article about partial differential equations. I don't have much to say myself about this so I'll just mention two examples.

The [Korteweg-de Vries equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) is of interest to people working in [integrable systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_systems) (there are other examples at that link). I understand that it has some interesting ties to algebraic geometry.

Another example (really a family of examples) is the following. Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$. This induces a map from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ to the Lie algebra of smooth vector fields on $M$, which induces an action of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $C^{\infty}(M)$ by differential operators. Choose $D \in U(\mathfrak{g})$. Then you can write down the differential equation
$$Df = 0$$

where $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. This differential equation should have order the degree of $D$ (with respect to the usual filtration on $U(\mathfrak{g})$). The space of solutions to this differential equation is acted on by the subgroup of $G$ commuting with $D$. In particular, if $D$ lies in the center, the space of solutions is acted on by all of $G$.

For a very simple example, let $G = \mathbb{R}$ act on itself by translation. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is spanned by ordinary differentiation $D$, the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is polynomials in $D$, and the corresponding differential equations you can write down are all linear homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients, all of which admit an action of $G$ (again by translation). Writing down this action explicitly gives generalizations of the angle addition formulas (which you obtain in the special case $D^2 + 1$).

For a non-abelian example, let $G = \text{SO}(3)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by rotation. Then the image of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so}(3)$ in vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is spanned by

$$L_x = y \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - z \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
$$L_y = z \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
$$L_z = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

These vector fields generate rotation about the $x, y, z$-axes respectively. The [Casimir operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_invariant)
$$L^2 = L_x^2 + L_y^2 + L_z^2$$

turns out to generate the center of $U(\mathfrak{so}(3))$, so the space of solutions to the differential equation $p(L^2) f = 0$ for any polynomial $p$ is acted on by all of $\text{SO}(3)$ and has order $2 \deg p$.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. Although, I'm still looking for more explicit formulas or names of equations even... Incidentally, do you have a source for the $\mathbb{R}$-translations and how they give generalizations of the angle addition formulas?

Comment: @James: nope. This is material that ought to be worked out immediately after the definition of the universal enveloping algebra in a textbook on Lie theory, but the textbooks on Lie theory that I've seen have other interests...